# Second 1394 Camera did not recognized in Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, camera, video-capture

Here's two 1394 camera with two capture card connected to PCI slots. In MS-Windows, the company application could capture both Digital cameras as well, but in Ubuntu, Only one camera (the camera which connected to the upper PCI slot) is detected, although both capture cards are recognized by Ubuntu
**note:** both camera/capture card work perfect in Ubuntu. Because each single camera/capture card mounting works OK.
*Does anyone have any solution?*

Comment: My guess would be, that you have no permissions to access the second camera. Try `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and (re)connect the device in question. Then try to `ls -lah /dev` and look at the permissions, the device file has. Maybe you need to construct an udev rule, to get permissions on the second device, but to test, a `chown youryouser:video /dev/devicename` should work.